# How to split refs into chunks that are pushed accross several commands?

Tags: git, github, git-push

Let’s say I have a repository with a large number of releases (tags). The repository is valid and git fsck report nothing.
But when I pushed the repository over ssh, I ended up with`remote: Internal Server Error`.

After investigating, it seems this the large number of refs which is the issue. I tried tried to set a repo with 4100 branches and the message was more verbose *(many`failed to lock`)*.

**Step to reproduce : push a repository with more than 5000 refs to a new empty repository on GitHub or GitHub enterprise.** Or just [fork this repo](https://github.com/ytrezq/TestBranches).

Is there a way to solve this without having to split the repo for pushing it in several parts ?

Comment: Can you create the new empty repository first, add something trivial to it, and then push?

Comment: Ok. I don't know how to solve your problem but I am wondering if this "limitation" is only on free github accounts? Would a paid plan remove this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem when trying to push a repo that had about 50,000 refs.
Github support indicated that my only option would be to push a smaller chunk of refs at once.

Here's the commandline I used (if you refs are located under a different namespace, i.e. `refs/replace`, use that instead of `refs/heads`).

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" --sort='authordate' refs/heads | xargs git push origin
```

Shells have a limit on how large a commandline string can be and xargs will intelligently split up the commands to stay under that limit. I found that Github was able to handle the amount that xargs was pushing at once but YMMV. If you're still hitting the Github limit, use the `max-args` option (some trial and error may be necessary).

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" --sort='authordate' refs/heads | xargs --max-args=<1000> git push origin
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to reproduce, but I guess it is a resource problem on the server side. Maybe an out of memory.

To verify this you can push one ref after the other. Start from the 'oldest' ref. That is the oldest commit in history that is referenced.

Just push one ref using a refspec. E.g. if the oldest ref is a tag named v1.0.0 do

```
git push <REMOTE_REPO> refs/tags/v1.0.0:refs/tags/v1.0.0
```

If it works you can go on with a little script.

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" --sort='authordate' refs/heads refs/tags | \
while read ref; 
do git push <REMOTE_REPO> $ref:$ref
done
```

Comment: @user2284570 Yes, there are repositories with a lot of refs on GitHub. But I guess they grew over time. I don't think that these large repositories were pushed at once. Where did you read about 50gb of ram? I'm not very active on github, but interessted in the limitations. Please provide a link.

Comment: Instead of updating one by one (which would lead to banning), I need to update with chunk of 4000 refs by git push.

Comment: An alternative is to [fork this repo](https://github.com/ytrezq/TestBranches). You’ll get an empty repo which is undeletable.